# Is it always necessary to duplicate a class template parameter when enabling constructors based on it?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, sfinae

Generally when using `enable_if` based on a class' template type, it is necessary to duplicate the class' template type as a template parameter of the constructor or method:

```
template <
    typename U = T,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_void<U>::value
    >::type
>
Class() { }
```

When exactly is this necessary (or not)?

For example, the following code compiles fine on G++, Clang and VC++...

```
template <typename T = void>
class Class {
public:
    template <
        typename U,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<
            // Is the use of T here allowed?
            std::is_void<T>::value
            || std::is_base_of<T, U>::value
        >::type
    >
    Class(U &&arg) {
        std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
    }

    template <
        typename U,
        typename ...U_Rest,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<
            // Is the use of T here allowed?
            !std::is_void<T>::value
            && !std::is_base_of<T, U>::value
        >::type
    >
    Class(U &&arg, U_Rest &&...rest) {
        std::cout << "Not Derived" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/jmGDLv) [rextester](http://rextester.com/EXBC97143)

... but uses `T` directly as part of the `enable_if`. Specifically, if `T` is `void`, the "Derived" version of the constructor will always be enabled, and the "Not Derived" version will always be disabled, regardless the parameters `U`.

Is the above actually legal according to the standard? Or do the compilers just accept it, probably due to a "no diagnostic required"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SFINAE applies to template method, and it should not be an hard failure (so mainly should depend of its template parameters).

Here your condition depends of `U`, so it is fine.

Note that you should prefer

```
template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<cond>* = nullptr>
```

over

```
template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<cond>>
```

to allow to write the *disabled* version

```
template <typename U, std::enable_if_t<!cond>* = nullptr>
```

as

```
template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<cond>> //...
template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<!cond>> // ...
```

have same signature.

Comment: In the case I posted, the condition does not depend on `U` if `T` is `void`. From your answer I gather that that would make it illegal?

Comment: Good point about the style. The reason I used `typename=std::enable_if_t` in this case is that the implementation is in a separate `.hpp`, and I didn't want to have to replicate the `enable_if` condition.

Comment: @zennehoy: You have `true || std::is_base_of<void, U>::value`, You think about short circuit but second operand might return special type with overloaded `operator ||`. so it depends. I would have a doubt for `true || sizeof(U) == 4`, but I think it is dependent anyway with the presence of `U`.